# Occurrence of a failure to migrate a Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

An error occurs when I use commands related to migration.

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/jch/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

As an exception, if I use "python3 managy.py makemigrations", "No changes detected" is output.

The first app is notice. If only notice connects to db, it will work normally.

```
#/notice/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model

class Notice(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

This is the second app, rc_db.

```
#/rc_db/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model

# Create your models here.
class rc_db(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

This is base.py, which is settings.py.

```
#/config/settings/base.py

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'info',
    'rcdb',
    'notice.apps.NoticeConfig',
    'rc_db.apps.RcDbConfig',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: You say `settings/base.py`, well  what are the contents of `settings/__init__.py`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat
__init__.py has no content. And __init__.py is located outside the settings folder.

Comment: Then why do you assume Django will use `settings/base.py` magically?

Comment: Because, A computer that develops and a computer that services are different computers.

Comment: It is divided into local.py used in the development computer and prod.py used in the service computer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It's solved when I put the separated settings.py back together! Thank you!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Oh, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!